# jQuery UI - Tabs Inside Accordion Breaking Size Constraint

Tags: jquery-ui, highlight.js

I'm displaying some code from a book and trying to organize it by chapters. Chapters 2-7 I have highlighted correctly and styled like desired. If I allow Chapter 2 which I'm trying to add tabs into the accordion it breaks the content size restrictions. Chapter 1 is me trying to load the code to be highlighted from other files like the other chapters and display them into tabs but I cannot highlight it without breaking the tabs from working properly. I'm new so this is definitely isn't written the best way. Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Btw this doesn't look exactly what I'm seeing since I'm get the accordion pages from other files. Thank you again.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#tabs2").tabs();
  $("#accordion").accordion({autoHeight:false,collapsible:true,"activate":false,heightStyle: "content",navigation: true});



  //$("#tabs").tabs();


  $.post("Blink.ino",function(postresult) {
    $("#pan1").append(postresult);
    $("#pan1").each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e);
    });
  });

  $.post("Ultimate_Machine.ino",function(postresult) {
    $("#pan1-2").append(postresult);
    $("#pan1-2").each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e);
    });
  });

  $.post("Twitter_Pet.ino",function(postresult) {
    $("#pan3").append(postresult);
    $("#pan3").each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e);
    });
  });

  $.post("Crystal_Ball.ino",function(postresult) {
    $("#pan4").append(postresult);
    $("#pan4").each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e);
    });
  });

  $.post("tardis.txt",function(postresult) {
    $("#pan5").append(postresult);
    $("#pan5").each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e);
    });
  });

  $.post("Train.ino",function(postresult) {
    $("#pan6").append(postresult);
    $("#pan6").each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e);
    });
  });

  $.post("tardis.txt",function(postresult) {
    $("#pan7").append(postresult);
    $("#pan7").each(function (i, e) {
      hljs.highlightBlock(e);
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- Highlight.js -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.8/styles/solarized-dark.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.8/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

```css
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    #accordion .ui-accordion-content {
      max-height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Arduino-LEGO-Projects-Jon-Lazar</h3>
<img src="./../SiteMaterial/books/LegoArduino/cover.jpg">
<img src="./../SiteMaterial/books/LegoArduino/android.png" />

<div id="accordion">
<!--
<h3><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></h3>
      <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
          <li><pre><code class="arduino" id="pan1"><a href="Blink.ino"></code></pre>Blink</a></li>
          <li><a href="Ultimate_Machine.ino">Ultimate Machine</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


// If Chapter 1&2 commented out it looks ideal
  <h3><a href="#">Chapter 2</a></h3>
  <div>
    <div id="tabs2">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">One_Ultrasonics_With_Lights.ino</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Three_Ultrasonics_With_Lights.ino</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tab-1">
        <pre><code class="arduino">
          // include the library for hobby servos
          #include <Servo.h>

          // DC hobby servo
          Servo servo1;

          // sets the constants for each of the sensor signal pins:
          const int pingPin[] = {2, 3, 4};

          // sets the increment counter for each sensor:
          int counter = 0;

          // sets the speed of the servo movement
          int spd = 10;

          // sets the left, right, and center positions of the servo
          int left = 10;
          int right = 170;
          int center = (right - left) / 2;

          // sets the variable to keep track of the servo angle
          int angle = center;

          void setup() {
            // initialize serial communication:
            Serial.begin(9600);

            // turn on servo and move to center
            servo1.attach(9);
            servo1.write(center);
          }

          void loop() {
            // establish variables for duration of the ping,
            // and the distance result in inches:
            long duration, inches;

            // resets counter if we run out of sensors
            if (counter == 3) counter = 0;

            // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
            // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
            pinMode(pingPin[counter], OUTPUT);
            digitalWrite(pingPin[counter], LOW);
            delayMicroseconds(2);
            digitalWrite(pingPin[counter], HIGH);
            delayMicroseconds(5);
            digitalWrite(pingPin[counter], LOW);

            // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
            // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
            // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
            pinMode(pingPin[counter], INPUT);
            duration = pulseIn(pingPin[counter], HIGH);

            // convert the time into a distance
            inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);

            // moves the servo to the left if left sensor is triggered
            if (inches < 6 && counter == 0) {
              if (angle != left) {
                for (int i=angle; i>left; i--) {
                  servo1.write(i);
                  delay(spd);
                }
                angle = left;
              }

            // moves to the center if center sensor is triggered
            } else if (inches < 6 && counter == 1) {
              // moves from left to center
              if (angle < center) {
                for (int i=angle; i<center; i++) {
                  servo1.write(i);
                  delay(spd);
                }
              // or moves from right to center
              } else {
                for (int i=angle; i>center; i--) {
                  servo1.write(i);
                  delay(spd);
                }
              }
              angle = center;

            // moves to the right if right sensor is triggered
            } else if (inches < 6 && counter == 2) {
              if (angle != right) {
                for (int i=angle; i<right; i++) {
                  servo1.write(i);
                  delay(spd);
                }
                angle = right;
              }

            // otherwise hold steady at the current position
            } else {
              servo1.write(angle);
            }

            // send the value in inches to the Serial Monitor for each sensor
            Serial.print("Sensor ");
            Serial.print(counter);
            Serial.print(": ");
            Serial.print(inches);
            Serial.println(" inches");

            // increment counter for the next loop
            counter++;

            // short delay before starting over again
            delay(100);
          }

          long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
            // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are
            // 73.746 microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per
            // second).  This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound
            // and return, so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
            // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
            return microseconds / 74 / 2;
          }



        </code></pre>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-2">
        <pre><code class="arduino">
            // sets the constants for the sensor and led signal pins:
            const int pingPin = 2;
            const int led = 10;

            void setup() {
              // initialize serial communication:
              Serial.begin(9600);

              // sets the LED pin to an output mode
              pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
            }

            void loop() {
              // establish variables for duration of the ping,
              // and the distance result in inches:
              long duration, inches;

              // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
              // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
              pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
              digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
              delayMicroseconds(2);
              digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
              delayMicroseconds(5);
              digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

              // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
              // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
              // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
              pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
              duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

              // convert the time into a distance
              inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);

              // turn on the led if object is within six inches
              if (inches < 6) {
                 digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
              } else {
                digitalWrite(led, LOW);
              }

              // send the value in inches to the Serial Monitor
              Serial.print(inches);
              Serial.println(" inches");

              // short delay before starting over again
              delay(100);
            }

            long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
              // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are
              // 73.746 microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per
              // second).  This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound
              // and return, so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
              // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
              return microseconds / 74 / 2;
            }


        </code></pre>
      </div>


      <div id="tab-3">
          <pre><code class="arduino">
            // sets the constants for each of the sensor and led signal pins:
            const int pingPin[] = {2, 3, 4};
            const int led[] = {10, 11, 12};

            // sets the increment counter for each sensor:
             int counter = 0;

            void setup() {
              // initialize serial communication:
              Serial.begin(9600);

              // sets each LED pin to an output mode
              for (int i=0; i<3; i++) pinMode(led[i], OUTPUT);
            }

            void loop() {
              // establish variables for duration of the ping,
              // and the distance result in inches:
              long duration, inches;

              // resets counter if we run out of sensors
              if (counter == 3) counter = 0;

              // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
              // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
              pinMode(pingPin[counter], OUTPUT);
              digitalWrite(pingPin[counter], LOW);
              delayMicroseconds(2);
              digitalWrite(pingPin[counter], HIGH);
              delayMicroseconds(5);
              digitalWrite(pingPin[counter], LOW);

              // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
              // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
              // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
              pinMode(pingPin[counter], INPUT);
              duration = pulseIn(pingPin[counter], HIGH);

              // convert the time into a distance
              inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);

              // turn on the led if object is within six inches
              if (inches < 6) {
                 digitalWrite(led[counter], HIGH);
              } else {
                digitalWrite(led[counter], LOW);
              }

              // send the value in inches to the Serial Monitor for each sensor
              Serial.print("Sensor ");
              Serial.print(counter);
              Serial.print(": ");
              Serial.print(inches);
              Serial.println(" inches");

              // increment counter for the next loop
              counter++;

              // short delay before starting over again
              delay(100);
            }

            long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
              // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are
              // 73.746 microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per
              // second).  This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound
              // and return, so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
              // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
              return microseconds / 74 / 2;
            }

          </code></pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div

-->


  <h3><a href="#">Chapter 3</a></h3>
  <div>
    <pre><code class="arduino" id="pan3"></code></pre>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Chapter 4</a></h3>
  <div>
    <pre><code class="arduino" id="pan4"></code></pre>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Chapter 5</a></h3>
  <div>
    <pre><code class="arduino" id="pan5"></code></pre>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Chapter 6</a></h3>
  <div>
    <pre><code class="arduino" id="pan6"></code></pre>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Chapter 7</a></h3>
  <div>
    <pre><code class="Arduino">
      #include <AFMotor.h>

      // Connect a stepper motor with 48 steps per revolution (7.5 degree)
      // to motor port #1 (M1 and M2)
      AF_Stepper motor(48, 1);

      int photocellPin = A0;     // the cell and 10K pulldown are connected to a0
      int photocellReading;     // the analog reading from the sensor divider
      int threshold = 200; // the amount of light required to activate the motor

      void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps

        motor.setSpeed(50);  // 50 rpm
      }

      void loop() {
          photocellReading = analogRead(photocellPin);

        Serial.print("Photocell reading = ");
        Serial.println(photocellReading);     // the raw analog reading

        if (photocellReading > threshold) {
          motor.step(100, FORWARD, INTERLEAVE);
        }


        delay(100);
      }
     </code></pre>
  </div>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No suggestions?